# Synthetic division without polynom package

Tags: tables

I have been working with some of my students on synthetic division, and I like how the book represents it in terms of keeping track of everything and the like. It made me wonder how best to reproduce what I have seen, and I put together what I am sure is some horrible code--my purpose in asking is to see whether or not there is a way to streamline my general idea (I'm not a big fan of the layout in the `polynom` package).

[image]

The above comes from the following garbled mess:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{2}{D{.}{}{2.0}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$}|>{$}r<{$}>{$}r<{$}>{$}r<{$}>{$}r<{$}}
-\frac{4}{3} & {3} & -1 & -6 & 12\\\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$-4$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$\frac{20}{3}$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$-\frac{8}{9}$} \\\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$-5$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$\frac{2}{3}$} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$\frac{100}{9}$}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should use array not tabular so you don't need `>{$}` (that is more or less the only difference between the environments. Then since you have `r` columns anyway you can remove all the `\multicolumnn{1}{r}` this would also have the advantage of always using math mode, as is you are using text for positive numbers and math for negative, which isn't guaranteed to use the same fonts for the digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{2}{D{.}{}{2.0}}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\doublerulesep{0pt}
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{-\frac{4}{3}} & {3} & -1 & -6 & 12\\\cline{2-5}
 & & -4& \frac{20}{3} & -\frac{8}{9}\\\cline{2-5}
 & 3 & -5& \frac{2}{3} & \frac{100}{9}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked very well. And thanks for the pointers!